# Should I use flash for photo galleries?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to use a flipping thumbnail photo gallery:

http://www.cincopa.com/media-platform/wizard_style.aspx?fid=new&defskin=tiltviewer

I hear that mozilla is not supporting flash:

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3160644/Google-Mozilla-pull-plug-Adobe-Flash-Tech-giants-disable-program-browsers-following-critical-security-flaw.html

Cannot find another flipping thumbnail photos gallery not built in flash.

I'm guessing that it is bad idea to use this gallery?

Do you know some other gallery like that but not in flash (jQuery || Wordpress plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

Flash is a sinking ship now a days.

http://occupyflash.org/

> http://clicknathan.com/about/no-flash/
>
> 1. Flash is not supported on iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch, or other
>    phones like the Blackberry Curve and Bold phones for Android, so
>    those users miss out completely on your site’s content (and
>    therefore leave your site as fast as they can get back to the Google
>    search bar).
> 2. Flash is not easily indexed by Google, so any content you have in
>    there is barely skimmed, at best. Your search result placement takes
>    the hit.
> 3. Flash is more expensive to develop and, unlike HTML5 & CSS3, isn’t
>    easily updated. Want to make a simple change like making all of your
>    links red instead of blue, that’ll take about 30 seconds with HTML &
>    CSS, but could take hours or even days to do with Flash.

Just a quick google search and you can find plenty of jQuery powered gallerys that have a similar effect

Heres a few:

http://www.webanddesigners.com/20-jquery-image-and-gallery-tutorials-and-plugins

http://flipgallery.net/

http://jqueryhouse.com/best-jquery-image-gallery-plugins

Answer (score 1):

Never use flash (as long as it isn't realy realy necessary), otherwise you'll make lots of people stop visiting your website... Reasons for this are eather that they can't deal with it because of natural limitations handicap (maybe the main reason) or they simply don't want to use flash because of security reasons.

There are lots of js-only-powered plugins for wordpress, just pick one:

http://smashingmesh.com/25-excellent-jquery-image-gallery-plugins-for-wordpress/ or http://www.tn3gallery.com/